# A Pattern Naming Curiosity: Why ActiveRecord and not ActionRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, design-patterns, naming-conventions, naming

I am really curious about this naming convention:
ActiveRecord, not ActionRecord
ActionMailer, not ActiveMailer
ActionController, not ActiveController

Basically, what I am asking is if there is a difference between using Active and Action?

Answer (score 1):

Because of the [active record pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_record_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Preesumably, because `ActiveRecord` represents a *database record*, which can *change/update dynamicaly* during run-time (thus is *active* and not an *action*)

On the other hand `ActionController` represents an *action* to be performed, similarly for `ActionMailer` and so on.

If it helps, see it as such:

- `Active` as an alias of `Dynamic`
- `Action` as an alias of `Command`

You can see the difference of concepts.